# How to fix DesiredCapabilities error in java appium?

Tags: java, appium

I am getting this error "The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

when I compile and run the program.

when I hover the mouse near the error location in the code this is the information its displaying.

""The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
package manoj_test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElemen0t;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class tes12 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "0260dd0730971a0a");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/home/manoj/Downloads/xyz.apk");
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);



}

}
```

Comment: Have you added **java-client** package in your project?

Comment: @SubanDhyako yes i have added it

Comment: @manoj I have posted the answer, please check that and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Please check your pom.xml and if you have a dependency of `selenium-remote-driver`, then remove that and check after that. It would work.
I also have faced the same issue in the past and i had the following dependency in my pom.xml and after removing it, the compilation error removed.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where to find pom.xml ??

Comment: If your project is of maven type, then you can expand your project and check all the files in it, you would find pom.xml and if your project is not of maven type and you have configured the dependencies manually, then check all the jars which are present in your project and find the `selenium-remote-driver` jar and remove that jar from your project.

Comment: I was able to solve it by downgrading my java version Sameer, the solution which you gave I was not able to find it. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after deleting the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same Issue , my project is not maven one and its the RAW code , so i figured out that my java version was 14 and i downgraded to 1.8